# How to execute scripts to import csv files inside a postgres deployed on a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, docker-volume, persistent-volumes

I'm trying to deploy Postgres on my Kubernetes cluster and I have been successful to do this, but then I don't know how I can import my data which are in csv format. I already have the scripts which gets the path to data and create a database in a local instance of postgres, but when I deploy postgres on Kubernetes cluster then those scripts wont work because I can't see those script inside the pod.

I was looking for a solution to execute the scripts from host to inside the pod, or I can expose the directory of scripts and data to postgres pod. 
I've found the hostpath solution, but I don't know how to define multiple volumes for a deployment. (I'm using Rook cluster to provision the volume)
Maybe a way to define a hostpath volume alongside a Rook volume so I can have access to the scripts and csv files inside the hostpath and then create the database inside the Rook volume. 
I don't know of this makes sense, but I would appreciate if someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), or an image that is derived from it but didn't destroy its entrypoint, then they have [documentation about `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.sql`](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres#how-to-extend-this-image), with the tl;dr as

```
kind: ConfigMap
spec:
  import_csv.sql: |
    COPY my_table FROM '/whatever/path/you/want.csv' FORMAT csv /* etc */
---
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - volumeMounts:
    - name: my-initdb-configmap
      mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      readOnly: true
    # ...
```

type deal

Comment: Of course, if your process is way more complex that just slurping in statically defined `.csv` files, they support running `.sh` files in the exact same way, but it would have made my answer more verbose so ...

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what can I do.